# Adding a user to Jira

Tags: jira

I'm the new Jira admin at my company, but can't for the life of me figure out how to add users to it. BitBucket seems to not sync its group members despite similar group names in the Jira "Users and roles" settings at https://company.atlassian.net/plugins/servlet/project-config/TLA/roles
and the user is not found in the "Add users to a role" box:
[image: No Matches]

According to [this page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/create-edit-or-remove-a-user-794198944.html), there seems to be a missing "User Management" option here:

[image: User Management?]

How can I add an existing BitBucket user to this Jira project?

Comment: Maybe i should allow creation of (duplicate) issues on BitBucket's issue tracker.

Comment: when i do it in confleunce, i'm assuming they're the same admin ui, i have a 'user configuration' option under the administration panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Global Permissions* (at `/secure/admin/GlobalPermissions!default.jspa`) there are *View Users* links, which a *Site Administrator* can grant access to.

As I see a "Add Permission" feature which appears to work, as i could add "Browse Users" permission to "administrators" group, i should be able to use that to grant myself access to add a user, presumably via aforementioned View Users links.

...or just wait for help from a Site Admin. Now i see (at `/admin/users`) as well, and can create users.